# Azure Text to speech SSML bookmark tags Error

Tags: text-to-speech, azure-cognitive-services

Encounter an internal server error when there is a bookmark in multi-language SSML for Chinese voices

```
<speak xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis" xmlns:mstts="http://www.w3.org/2001/mstts" xmlns:emo="http://www.w3.org/2009/10/emotionml" version="1.0" xml:lang="en-US"><voice name="yue-CN-YunSongNeural"><prosody rate="0%" pitch="0%">

试用唔同嘅语言同声音。改变语速同音调。你甚至可以调整SSML（语音合成标记语言），嚟控制文本唔同部分嘅声音效果。单击上面嘅 SSML 试用一下！
<bookmark mark="pronounce_1" />
请尽情使用文本转语音功能！</prosody></voice></speak>
```

there would be return correct audio data from the response

Answer (score 0):

The bookmark element is incompatible with the prosody and break elements. You can't adjust pause and prosody like pitch, contour, rate, or volume in this element. You can find more information for SSML [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/cognitive-services/Speech-Service/speech-synthesis-markup-voice.md).

Here's a subset of the basic structure and syntax of an SSML document:

```
<speak version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis" xmlns:mstts="https://www.w3.org/2001/mstts" xml:lang="string">
    <mstts:backgroundaudio src="string" volume="string" fadein="string" fadeout="string"/>
    <voice name="string">
        <audio src="string"/></audio>
        <bookmark mark="string"/>
        <break strength="string" time="string" />
        <emphasis level="value"></emphasis>
        <lang xml:lang="string"></lang>
        <lexicon uri="string"/>
        <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"></math>
        <mstts:audioduration value="string"/>
        <mstts:express-as style="string" styledegree="value" role="string"></mstts:express-as>
        <mstts:silence type="string" value="string"/>
        <mstts:viseme type="string"/>
        <p></p>
        <phoneme alphabet="string" ph="string"></phoneme>
        <prosody pitch="value" contour="value" range="value" rate="value" volume="value"></prosody>
        <s></s>
        <say-as interpret-as="string" format="string" detail="string"></say-as>
        <sub alias="string"></sub>
    </voice>
</speak>
```